# Mysql stores a number instead of the value set

Tags: mysql, numbers, datastore

I have a problem with mysql storing a number value instead of the value I set in a form.

I can't find my problem or solution on the net.

A summary of code of what's happening.

**HTML form code:**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="load_ericsson" value="Ericsson"> Ericsson</td>
```

**Connect.php code:**

```
$load_ericsson = isset($_POST['load_ericsson']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO load_ericsson (contract) VALUES ('$load_ericsson')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

**Result in phpmyadmin:**
It should say "Ericsson" as a value in the entry (because that is the value in the html form).

Instead the contract column in the load_ericsson table has a value of "1"

Comment: Please anyone? Im so hung up on this. I CANNOT get it to work! I read ALL forums, i watched all youtube vids and looked in my books. Either i use what i had and get a value of 1 OR i use Kostas code and when its unchecked i get and undefined variable error. PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vaue of `isset($_POST['load_ericsson'])` will be `true` or `false`. Also it's better to use PDO and prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection and because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

You need this:

```
if (isset($_POST['load_ericsson'])) {
    $load_ericsson = $_POST['load_ericsson'];
    //query with validation, sanitization, prepared statement here
}
```

Comment: Wauw, i was still editing my question and already i got an answer.
Where would we be without you people? Thanks, let me check it out and get back here...

Comment: Ouch! I forgot the reason why i coded it that way.
Being, now when i leave the checkbox unchecked and i submit the form
I get:

Notice: Undefined variable: load_ericsson in C:\xampp\htdocs\heijunka\files\connect1.php on line 147

Comment: Please anyone? Im so hung up on this. I CANNOT get it to work!
I read ALL forums, i watched all youtube vids and looked in my books.
Either i use what i had and get a value of 1 OR i use Kostas code and when its unchecked i get and undefined variable error.
PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!